# Different shapes according to data in D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to have a force layout where there are two types of shapes: Circles and Triangles. However, I get an error- Cannot read property 'symbol' of undefined. This is the relevant code snippet:

```
var shape = {"action": "circle", "why-hard": "triangle"};    

var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) { return shape[d.type]; }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely using d3v4. D3v4 has a number of namespace changes that will break code from v3, and it appears your symbol code is from v3. In this example:

```
.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) { return shape[d.type]; }))
```

will give the error: *`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'symbol' of undefined`* (as noted) in Chrome, and *`d3.svg is undefined`* in Firefox. Instead for v4 try something along the lines of:

```
 .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross));
```

To assign type dynamically in v4, the approach is essentially the same as you have:

```
 .attr("d", d3.symbol().type( function(d,i) { return d3.symbols[i];} ) )
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fwj6jjLa/1/).

See https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#symbol for v4 documentation regarding shapes.